# SQL Between query not work properly

Tags: mysql, forms, date, report, between

```
SELECT * FROM `incomes` WHERE incomeDate BETWEEN '28-12-2016' and '31-01-2017'
```

This query not work but When i do below query it show result

```
SELECT * FROM `incomes` WHERE incomeDate BETWEEN '28-12-2016' and '31-12-2016'
```

Comment: ... what is the datatype of the `incomeDate` column? Is that declared as  a `DATE` or a `VARCHAR`?  Note that the string literals in format dd-mm-yyyy  are *not* canonical; comparison of strings occurs character by character, left to right.  So, a string value of `'29-07-1999'` will be *between* the two string literals, but taken to represent a *date*, the date isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Please change date format, MYSQL Support 'YYYY-MM-DD' date formates in comparion. Please use below query.

```
SELECT * FROM incomes WHERE incomeDate BETWEEN '2016-12-28' and '2017-01-31'.
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a date column to (two) string literals. What happens here is the date is converted to a string and compares lexicographically. Instead, you should explicitly convert the strings to dates, and thus compare them by date order:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   incomes 
WHERE  incomeDate BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('28-12-2016', '%d-%m-%Y') AND 
                          STR_TO_DATE('31-01-2017', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: Well, it's always a lexicographic comparison!